# Vim - don't delete upon visual paste

Tags: vim

Copying a word into a register, selecting a different word with visual mode, and pasting over the second word deletes the original word in the register.

For example, running `vey` on Word_1, then running `vep` on Word_2 now puts Word_2 in the `"*` register. I would like the `"*` register to maintain the Word_1 value. Any ideas?

I was thinking of mapping paste in visual mode to a custom range function, saving the register before pasting, and then restoring the register after pasting. I just need some help doing that.

Comment: `"0` will always be what you last yanked. See `:h quote0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install [vim-operator-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user) and [vim-operator-replace](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-replace)